# Unable to compile applescript from NSString

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I've been trying to figure out how to run applescript in a objective-c program but so far haven't been able to.

Regardless of how I load the source into the `NSAppleScript` object, I simply can't get it to compile. Loading from a file returns a `nil` and loading from source just plain refuses to compile.

I am not an objective-c programmer in any respect and I am having a hard time figuring out how this <strike>brain dead</strike> language works. Any and all problems are likely correlated to my inability to comprehend why a constructor changes its name based on the arguments you give it.

Example source of one of my many attempts: (note, the script is correct and works fine in Script Editor)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString * source =
        @"to go_home()\n"
        "    tell application \"Finder\" to open \"Home\"\n"
        "end go_home\n"
        "go_home()";

        NSAppleScript * script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: source];

        if ( script == nil)
            NSLog(@"Script is nil");

        NSLog(@"Script source = %@", script.source);

        [script compileAndReturnError: nil];
        [script executeAndReturnError: nil];

        if ([script isCompiled])
            NSLog(@"Script is compiled");
        else
            NSLog(@"Script is not compiled");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
2017-12-05 11:05:48.249206+0100 applescript[11826:744415] Script source = to go_home()
    tell application "Finder" to open "Home"
end go_home
go_home()
2017-12-05 11:05:48.262797+0100 applescript[11826:744415] Script is not compiled
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

*Edit*: It appears that the problem is related to XCode. When I compile the program in a terminal, everything works fine.

Comment: It worked to me:
2017-12-06 09:25:15.214 applescript test[1979:114306] Script source = to go_home()
    tell application "Finder" to open "Home"
end go_home
go_home()
2017-12-06 09:25:15.606 applescript test[1979:114306] Script is compiled
Program ended with exit code: 0

macOS 10.11.6 - Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @MichelePercich I got it working outside of XCode. The only reply to this question already gives me the same information that you provide.

Comment: My test was in Xcode too. I'm supposing there is an issue with more recent releases of OS X - Xcode, so I mentioned my quite dated system versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am getting **Script is compiled
Program ended with exit code: 0** for same code. 
you can check error by replacing

```
[script compileAndReturnError: nil];
[script executeAndReturnError: nil];
```

with

```
 NSDictionary *error;
 [script compileAndReturnError: &error];
 [script executeAndReturnError: &error];
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", error)` gives `2017-12-05 12:13:58.816092+0100 applescript[11976:768231] {
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2147450879";
}` for both compile and execute.

Comment: When I compile it outside of XCode and run it there, everything works fine. The script even runs just like it's supposed to.